# Selenium Side Runner Selecting Wrong ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am experiencing differences in how the Selenium IDE and Selenium SIDE Runner are executing some test cases

On a company development website, one page has multiple dropdowns that are to be mapped to match the column headers of an uploaded spreadsheet. the IDs of each of these dropdowns are sequential-
DropdownOrderList_0_, DropdownOrderList_1_, and so on. When I record this test it registers a click event for when I open and select a title from each dropdown. This executes without issue from the IDE. However when I execute this same test through the command line / side runner, instead of each dropdown being selected, the first dropdown is instead selected multiple times. This is made even stranger by the fact that the "click" events are still being registered on the correct dropdowns, but the "select" events are not. [Here is what that part of the Selenium script looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmbVN.png) [Here is what that part of the website looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9AL1.png) Has anybody else encountered anything like this and if so what steps did you take to resolve it? Thank you!

*edit* I wanted to update you all that I was able to find assistance with this through a co-worker- it seems like Selenium might have a bug in selecting drop-downs by label when executed from selenium SIDE Runner. The way I worked around this was to instead select the label by its index- so instead of 'label=Annual Salary' the target was 'index=1'